# jQuery plugin mmenu

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I have a problem with the mmenu; I cannot figure out how to install the plugin, since it's the first time I work with it. What exactly is the problem I watch the tutorials where it is everywhere written to connect

```
Path / to / js / jquery.mmenu.all.min.js
```

But when downloading there is no such folder js, and even more so a minified file

Comment: where is the code????

Comment: `path/to/js...` is a figurative, symbolic way of saying that you should use a relative path to the JS file. I'm quite sure you don't have folders called "Path", "to", and "js" in your system in successive nesting order.

Answer (score 0):

Create the folder(s), with the names of your choice, and download the file from:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/6.1.5/jquery.mmenu.all.js

(right-click the link, and "Save link as...")

Then reference it with that relative folder and name (without `.min`, unless you added that to the name while saving it).